# Check for 'null' on value and reference types

Tags: c#, class, generics, types, null

I'm currently a little confused about checking for 'null' (empty, not available, without value) on value and or reference types. There seem to be a lot of possible ways to do so and all of them are frequently used.

Let's say I've got the following extension method which can be used somehow similar to a maybe monad:

```
public static TResult UseWith<T, TResult>(this T value, Func<T, TResult> action)
{
    // if value not null
    //     execute action
    // else return the default value of 'TResult'
}
```

So? How do I check for null?

```
if(value != null)
```

or (which checks for null on reference types, but for default on value types)

```
if(!Equals(value, default(T))
```

or

```
if(!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, default(T))
```

or (with precheck)

```
 if (!typeof(T).IsValueType)
 {
     if (Equals(source, default(T))) 
          return TResult; 
 }
```

Or is it better to create 2 methods with restrictions?

```
 public static TResult UseWith<T, TResult>(this T value, Func<T, TResult> action)
    where T : class
 {
    if(value == null)

  public static TResult UseWith<T, TResult>(this T value, Func<T, TResult> action)
    where T : struct
 {
    if(value.HasValue)
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `T? value` in the final method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pseudocode in your first snippet will simply work exactly as you want it to.  A variable that is typed as an unbounded generic argument can be compared to `null` using the `==` operator.  The code will compile, and it will simply evaluate to `false` whenever `T` is a non-nullable value type.

You don't want to compare `T` to the default value, because the default value may not be `null`.

There is no need to explicitly check if `T` is a value type, or have separate overloads for reference/value types, as the `==` operator handles this when it's JITted.

Comment: @xvdiff `HasValue` is only valid on nullable value types, and it is functionally equivalent to comparing it with null.  The default value of a nullable value type is `null`, so that will be identical to comparing it to null.  If you pass a nullable value type that is `null` it will be equal to `null`.  If you pass a nullable value type that is not `null` then it's not equal to `null`.